# Remove dependency on sequential id values in React code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This [codepen](https://codepen.io/simonswiss/pen/memmZN) filters names using an array of objects in the following format with sequential `id` values.

```
const PEOPLE = [
  {
    id: 0,
    name: 'Aria',
    sex: 'girl'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Logan',
    sex: 'boy'
  }]
```

I am trying to learn how to modify this so any nonsequential `id` value could be used. i.e.

```
const PEOPLE = [
      {
        id: 0,
        name: 'Aria',
        sex: 'girl'
      }, {
        id: 100,
        name: 'Logan',
        sex: 'boy'
      }]
```

My understanding is that the code currently has a dependency between the position of a name in the `PEOPLE` array and the numerical `id` value as any change to `id` values has the code return incorrect results.

**What have I tried:**

I think something like this could be used but I'm not sure how to implement it in this Codepen example .

```
const isIndex = (element) => element == id
array.findIndex(isIndex)
```

**Additional information as requested.**

The `ShortList` functionality does not work if the `id` is not sequential as shown below where "Logan" is searched for but "Lachlan" is added as it has the modified index value of 100.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're simply trying to find an element by id

```
const findById = id => array.find(element => element.id === id);
```

> The `find()` method returns the **value** of the **first element** in the
>   provided array that satisfies the provided testing function.

It returns `undefined` if not found.

If you *really* want the index

```
const findIndexById = id => array.findIndex(element => element.id === id);
```

> The `findIndex()` method returns the **index** of the first element in the
>   array **that satisfies the provided testing function**. Otherwise, it
>   returns `-1`, indicating that no element passed the test.

```js
const PEOPLE = [{
  id: 350,
  name: 'Aria',
  sex: 'girl'
}, {
  id: 100,
  name: 'Logan',
  sex: 'boy'
}];

const findById = (array, id) => array.find(element => element.id === id);
const findIndexById = (array, id) => array.findIndex(element => element.id === id);

console.log(findById(PEOPLE, 100));
console.log(findIndexById(PEOPLE, 100));
```

**Resolution:**

Line 34 in `ShortList`, change `info={data[fav]}` to `info={data.find(person => person.id === fav)}`. When all the people *are* in order and id sequentially increase from 0, then `data[id]` works, but if the array can have a different order then that breaks and you need to search for it.

```
<Name 
  id={i}
  key={i}
  info={data.find(person => person.id === fav)}
  handleFavourite={(id) => deleteFavourite(id)}
/>
```

Comment: How would you use this in the linked Codepen please?

Comment: @ade1e IDK, I don't see where you try any filtering by id other than checking if a person is "favourited" already (*Is that the line? Line 73?*), the other filtering is by `person.name`. The `favourites` array stores ids. Can you be more specific with what/where you are trying to do this other filtering? That js file is 1000+ lines of code.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I updated the question to show that the `ShortList` functionality does not work.  Line 17.

Comment: @ade1e Ah, ok, I think I found it. Line 34 in `ShortList`, change `info={data[fav]}` to `info={data.find(person => person.id === fav)}`. When all the people *are* in order and id sequentially increase from 0, then `data[id]` works, but if the array can have a different order then that breaks and you need to search for it.